# PHP Custom Class, PayPal API, Mailgun API, Easypost API. Can they work together

Tags: php, pdo, paypal, mailgun, easypost

I have an ecommerce site that i am building for a client. This site had previously worked perfectly fine using procedural functions and curl to make the calls to Paypal. I download the Mailgun and Easypost API manual and installed manually. DOwn the road, I wanted to update the site to utilize PDO & OOP. I have done a fair job at getting the foundation laid. Now it is time to start making calls to the various API's.I installed everything using composer and currently run a dual autoloader. The composer autoload and then beneath it a custom autoload to load my classes. Now, when I call on the PayPal API, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Paypal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in /var/www/html/myla-dev/shoppingCartFinalize.php on line 18
```

I think what is happening is my autoloader is trying to load this rather than the composers autoloader. Here is where the autoloading is occurring:

init.php

```
require __DIR__.'/core/functions/general.php';
function autoLoader ($class) {
  if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/core/classes/'.$class.'.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/core/classes/'.$class.'.php';
  }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoLoader');
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This file sits in project root directory and is then required at the top of every file.

File Structure

```
core
--classes
----Alert.php
----....
--functions
----general.php
vendor
--composer
--easypost
--guzzle
--mailgun
--symfony
--paypal
--autoload.php
index.php
init.php
...
```

composer.json

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-php"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "easypost/easypost-php": "dev-master",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php":"*",
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

Any and all assistance is appreciated. If you feel like writing code, GREAT, but that is not what I am asking for. That is my job, but help with reworking to make it work would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: post your composer.json file

Comment: Sorry it took so long. I had to work last night. OP is updated with the composer.json file. Thank You

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure a 100% that you actually have the Paypal api installed ? Double check by verifying if the file really exists. You can also just re-do a `composer update` or `composer dumpautoload` to regenerate the autoload.

Comment: That was the first step in my troubleshooting process. Obviously it didn't work.

Comment: I cannot test this right now, but your advice will encourage me, hopefully, till tomorrow night when I have time to continue troubleshooting. Can I fix this by sticking my classes folder and my vender in the same folder along with the composer autoloader and then requiring the autoloader in my init.php file?

Comment: You can have multiple autoloader functions. Your custom autoloader function should not be a problem. You can always try not to add your autoload function and just do a simple `$test = new Paypal\Rest\ApiContext()` and see what happens. I suspect your problem is a `code 18` type of problem. You can also try to add your folder so it get scanned by composer's autoloader : https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a simple syntax error. After I dumped and updated composer it still failed to work, so I just copied the code from the installation wiki. It worked so I composer their code to mine and I was missing a backslash in my call to the wiki. Thank you for your assistance though.